# My service is stopped or paused after a while

Tags: android, service, background

I am running a service using startService(), and works well, keep running but only for a while, then stops working, or paused.

when I close my app, called unbindservice to not close the service and it works well.
but over time, approximately 30 min service stops working, but still remains in the list of running services .. What will be happening?
I do not know if I explained well :s

Comment: A stab in the dark - your main background thread silently hits an exception and dies. This doesn't kill the service, but now the service doesn't have a thread to respond to requests.

Answer (score 2):

This usually happens if you start your service as a background service.  The OS can decide to kill it at any time.

You can give your service more 'importance' by making it a [foreground service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground%28int,%20android.app.Notification%29).  You also have the option of specifying what's known as a redelivery flag in the [onStartCommand](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand%28android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int%29).  It's what the OS would use to re-start your service when needed, and you can have it redeliver any intents you used to start it in the first place.

Comment: using foreground shows me in the notification bar. but somehow it does not show it? I can call without displaying notification?